# Concerning Rabies can an animal feeding on rabid bat transmit right away?

Tags: zoology, virology

Playful kitten found biting and toying with a dead bat. Lets say the kitten nips and plays rough with a human right after biting and toying with the bat.

Will a potential rabies virus transmit from the mouth of the kitten into the human being that it may still harbor the virus from the bat?

Putting aside the fact that the rabies virus takes days to weeks to infect the kitten, can the virus cross contaminate from the mouth or nails of the cat if the feline was playing with the corpse?

Comment: Yes, [there is a possibility](https://www.cdc.gov/rabies/transmission/exposure.html) that a kitten can transmit the virus if that kitten had fresh infected bat blood or saliva on it's claws or teeth and gets it directly into your eyes, nose, mouth, or a wound. It's very rare and exceedingly hard to prove, however. These are called non-bite exposures.